# How does this route to different nodes?

Tags: elixir

I am looking at [this official tutorial](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks.html). I don't understand how this will route to different nodes. It looks like it will simply invoke the `route` function again and wait.

Can you please explain?

```c
def route(bucket, mod, fun, args) do
    # Get the first byte of the binary
    first = :binary.first(bucket)

    # Try to find an entry in the table() or raise
    entry =
      Enum.find(table(), fn {enum, _node} ->
        first in enum
      end) || no_entry_error(bucket)

    # If the entry node is the current node
    if elem(entry, 1) == node() do
      apply(mod, fun, args)
    else
      {KV.RouterTasks, elem(entry, 1)}
      |> Task.Supervisor.async(KV.Router, :route, [bucket, mod, fun, args])
      |> Task.await()
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Task.Supervisor.async/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async/5) spawns the task on the node passed as a second element of the first argument when it’s an `{atom(), node()}` tuple.

In the snippet above, the code under last `else` is passing `{KV.RouterTasks, elem(entry, 1)}` as the first argument, where `elem(entry, 1)` is the node to spawn the task on.